# fail DF show pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, show

```
!pip install Pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
pdf = pd.read_excel("xxxx.xlsx", sheet_name='Input (I)')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.show()
```

But get an error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.showString.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (10.75.81.111 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like related to the communication between PySpark and Python that might be solved by changing the environment variable's values:

```
Set Env PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
```

But, why don't you load the xlsx file directly on a PySpark DF? Something like:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
                            .option("useHeader", "true") \
                            .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                            .option("dataAddress", "Input (I)") \
                            .load("xxxx.xlsx"))
```